# copying files with particular names to another folder

Tags: command-line, file-copy

I have a folder with a lot of files. I want to copy all files which begin with of these names (separated by space):

```
abc abd aer ab-x ate
```

to another folder. How can I do that?

Comment: so the filename consists of `abc abd aer ab-x ate`

Comment: no begins with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh93`, `bash`, `fish` or `zsh -o cshnullglob`, you can use [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) and [globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) to do that (`--` is not needed for these filenames, but I assume they are just examples):

```
cp -- {abc,abd,aer,ab-x,ate}* dest/
```

If you'd rather not use brace expansion, you can use a for loop (here POSIX/Bourne style syntax):

```
for include in abc abd aer ab-x ate; do
    cp -- "$include"* dest/
done
```

If you have a very large amount of files, this might be slow due to the invocation of `cp` once per include. Another way to do this would be to populate an array, and go from there (here `ksh93`, `zsh` or recent `bash` syntax):

```
files=()
includes=(abc abd aer ab-x ate)

for include in "${includes[@]}"; do
    files+=( "$include"* )
done

cp -- "${files[@]}" dest/
```

Comment: She/He said copy (`cp`) not move (`mv`) ;) You're too fast :)

Comment: In fact I have a much longer list than `abc,abd,aer,ab-x,ate` (the list shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485430/installing-from-a-folder-of-debian-files) ). Is there a way to omit the commas? Or a way to insert the commas automatically

Comment: @user69453 I've added another option to the answer as per your request.

Answer (score 3):

A note about brace expansion vs globbing.

Brace expansion is not globbing (though the distinction is not as clear in csh/tcsh where it originated as in other shells). It is performed *before* globbing.

So, when you do:

```
cp {a,b}* /dest
```

It is first expanded to:

```
cp a* b* /dest
```

That means that the shell will have to expand two globs, that is get the full list of files twice and see which match the pattern twice.

With `zsh`, that also means that if any of the glob doesn't match any file, the whole command is cancelled (which you can work around by enabling the `cshnullglob` option to behave like in csh).

That also means that if you have

```
cp {a,ab}* /dest
```

`cp` will copy the `ab*` files twice.

That's different from the:

```
cp @(a|b)* /dest
```

of `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`, or

```
cp (a|b)* /dest
```

of `zsh`. There, it's only *one* glob, so it will be more efficient, and files will only be included once.

With `zsh`, if you've got the list of prefixes in an array:

```
prefixes=(abc abd aer ab-x ate)
cp -- (${(j:|:)~prefixes})* /dest
```

(above, the prefixes are treated as globs). That is join the elements of the arrays with `|` and consider the result as a glob (`~`).

If the list is big, what you may find is that executing `cp` fails with an *"arg list too long"* error. In that case, you can use `zsh` builtin version of `cp` which you can by loading the `zsh/files` module (`zmodload zsh/files`).

Answer (score 2):

1. For example I have these files in current directory:

   ```
   1-s2.0-S0038092X0000058X-main.pdf  ANNDHW.pdf     HPcalculation2
   1-s2.0-S0306261999000422-main.pdf  ANNlee.pdf     HPcalculation3
   ANNCanada.pdf                      HPcalculation  HPcalculation4
   ```
2. I want to move all the files starting from HP to folder: `./NewFolder/`
3. I can do:

   ```
   cp ./HP* ./NewFolder/
   ```

   `./HP*` will tell linux that I am interested in all the files starting from HP. The reverse is when I am interested in moving all the files ending with `.pdf`. I can put `*` in front of the `.pdf`:

   ```
   cp ./*.pdf ./NewFolder/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do

```
 cp abc* abd* aer* ab-x* ate*  DestinationPath
```

A solution to your extended problem can be

1. put all the filenames in a list e.g. list0.txt
2. Copy all with

   cp  `cat list0.txt` DestinationPath   # Needs no whitespace in the filenames

   or, better,

   while read -r file; do cp "$file" dest/ ; done < list0.txt

Notes:

- "$file" because so you can handle name with white space inside as `One Package.deb`
- `-r` it protect you from escape sequences.

> -r Backslash does not act as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part of the line.  In particular, a  backslash-
>   newline pair may not be used as a line continuation

Comment: This will not work; pathname expansion is not performed when encountering globs in weak quoting.

Comment: @ChrisDown Thx I was too fast too :)

Comment: Your list approach will fail on filenames with whitespace. You should use `while read file; do cp "$file" dest/ ; done < list0.txt` instead.

Comment: Right, even safer `read -r`. BTW this example was related to a list of package names of ubuntu with no whitespace inside.@terdon Thx for the spot.

Comment: You need `IFS= read -r` for the leading and trailing blank characters not to be removed. Also note that the newline character is as valid as any in a filename.