# How to execute "mv" command with conditions - move files with certain ending to other folder

Tags: linux, terminal, mv

I am a computer science student. Second year of school - and I'm learning about Linux. Because of the Corona virus, I study in an independent way. During my studies I came across a question with a number of sections - I can't solve it.

The question wants me to execute the `mv` command - that I transfer some files to the folder. I tried to execute the `mv` command - and tried to integrate "pipe" or other commands like `find`.

This is not a normal `mv` command in my opinion, more things need to be integrated, how I can't decipher it. I tried to solve the question for a few days. I also tried to find such identical questions in the forum - but I couldn't find them.

The question:

1. Write one command that will copy all files ending in `.c` or `.h` into the `Programs` folder.

*My try was maybe do that:*

```
find "*.c" -o "*.h" | mv Programs
```

Comment: Welcome @Haham to Unix SE. As a new user, please make yourself familar with the specific Q&A style of this site. You may start with this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is not good?

Comment: Unfortunately not. (1) It is 3 questions. (2) You don't show what you tried and how that failed. Actually, your task is relatively easy and you will find answers on this site when you search.

Comment: I'll fix it right away

Comment: is it good now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copying files with particular names to another folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138007/copying-files-with-particular-names-to-another-folder)

Comment: It helped, but I'm not sure if my solution will work
I should probably do this:
cp -- *{.c,.h} /Programs
but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you know how to list files ending in "c"?  Do you have a computer to try out `ls *.c`? Have you ever moved or copied a file?

Comment: Yes, but not with the "mv" command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment can be interpreted in three ways:

1. Copy all `.c` and `.h` files *from the current directory* to the directory `Programs`, or
2. Copy all `.c` and `.h` files *from the current directory or anywhere below it* to the directory `Programs`.
3. Copy all accessible `.c` and `.h` *from anywhere on the system* to the directory `Programs`.

Note that the assignment says "copy", not "move". This means that you should be using the `cp` command, not `mv`.

The first interpretation of the assignment is solved by

```
cp *.[ch] Programs
```

(assuming that `*.[ch]` matches all files we're interested in, and there's not many thousands of these in the current directory).

The second interpretation of the assignment is solved by

```
find . -path ./Programs -prune -o -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec cp {} Programs \;
```

This searches for all regular files with a `.c` or `.h` filename suffix in or below the current directory, and executes `cp` for each such file.  We can't pipe to `cp` since that utility does not read its standard input stream.

We also make sure to *avoid* looking inside the `Programs` directory (assumed to be a subdirectory in the current directory).  Not doing that would end up copying files from `Programs` into `Programs`. See "[Explain find's -path and -prune options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376075/explain-finds-path-and-prune-options)" for more info about `-path` and `-prune`.

The third interpretation is easy to implement from the second:

```
find / -path "$PWD/Programs" -prune -o -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec cp {} Programs \;
```

... we just need `find` to start at the top of the directory tree and to specify that the `Programs` directory to avoid is the one at the path `$PWD/Programs`.

This will likely throw a number of errors at you due to you not having access everywhere. To avoid this, also prune  directories that you can't access and only copy files that you can read:

```
find / \( -type d ! -executable -o -path "$PWD/Programs" \) -prune -o \
    -type f -name '*.[ch]' -readable -exec cp {} Programs \;
```

This requires GNU `find` for the `-executable` test (a directory is searchable if it's executable) and the `-readable` test.

Note that the `find` variations here will restrict the files to only regular files (through the `-type f` test), while the `cp *.[ch]` approach would copy any type of thing that ends in those two characters. Also, the `find` solution would copy hidden files (files with names that begin with a dot), while the first solution would not match those types of names by default.

Comment: that was helpful